# PowerShell mapped network drives not persisting after logout

Tags: networking, hard-drive, powershell

The command I'm running to map a network drive is:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "M" -PsProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\domain.com\filepath" -Persist -Scope Global -Credential $userCredentials
```

The command maps the drive and the connection persists after closing the script, but after logging out & back in the drive disappears. I'm under the impression that adding the global scope supersedes the need for dot-sourcing, which I'd rather not do for the sake of this script.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions/answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone else who gets to this question: after the drive is mapped, in the user registry under HKCU\Network\ [drive letter] there are two keys that need value changes BEFORE logging out and back in:

Change the DWORD value of ConnectionType to 1, and the DWORD value of DeferFlags to 4. This magically fixed it for me, so the drive persists!